# Vis.js change the .css file

Tags: javascript, css, vis.js, vis.js-network

I want to change the underlying .css file of the vis.js library.
However, the changes are not reflected and I am even losing on features like "tooltips" or "navigation buttons".

I've tried to put the following into my .html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
             src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vis/4.16.1/vis-network.min.js">
</script>
<link href="/node_modules/vis/dist/vis.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

All I want is to change the color of the navigation buttons and the tooltips.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

This Q is rather old, but just for the record:

From what I've seen, elements in VIS networks are styled via settings of the function passed to it when the graph is rendered. This is probably because vis.js renders the graph to a HTML canvas which is basically a black box for browser and it cannot apply any styling to it dynamically.

So, head over to the docs http://visjs.org/docs/network/ and read up what's possible. Generally, you can change color {fill, border, text}, font family, fontsize, shapes of nodes, style of edges, etc.

Also, very useful is the examples gallery: http://visjs.org/network_examples.html

Example of my settings:

```
    var options = {
    // tree style
    layout: {
        // this would make the tree directed
        // hierarchical: {
        //     direction: LR,
        //     sortMethod: directed
        // },
        // this makes the tree always the same
        randomSeed:2
    },
    interaction: {
        dragNodes :false,
        navigationButtons: true, // these need some more CSS
        keyboard: true
    },
    // read the docs for this
    physics: {
        barnesHut: {
          avoidOverlap: 0.99,
          gravitationalConstant: -3300,
          springLength: 150,
        },
        minVelocity: 0.75,
        timestep: 0.9,

        stabilization: {
            enabled:true,
            iterations:1000,
            updateInterval:25
        }               
    },
    // general nodes settings
    nodes: {
        shape: 'box',
        font: {
            size: 14,
            color: '#3f3f3f',
            strokeWidth: 3, 
            strokeColor: 'white',
            face: 'akrobat'
        },
        borderWidth: 2,
        color: {
            background: '#d7d7f3',
            border: '#3030a9',
        }

    },
    // settings for groups of nodes
    groups: {
        first: {
            shape: 'diamond',
            size: 5
        },
        second: {
            shape: 'dot',
            size: '8',
            font: {
                strokeWidth: 0,
                size: 18
            },
            color: {
                background: '#f3d7d7',
                border: '#a93030'
            }
        }
    },
    // general edges setting
    edges: {
        font: {
            align: 'middle',
            face: 'arial'
        },
        smooth: {
          forceDirection: none
        }
    }
};
```